# Como Implementar AutoMapper 6.2.2

Tags: c#, automapper

Estou seguindo um [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9Il79a2uBU) no qual as classes estão configuradas da seguinte maneira:

Uma classe chamada AutoMapperConfig:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {

        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
            x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
        });

    }
}
```

Uma outra classe chamada DomainToViewModelMappingProfile, que faz o mapeamento de Dominio para ViewModel:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
        CreateMap<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>();
    }

}
```

E uma terceira chamada ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile que mapeia de ViewModel para o Domínio:

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
        CreateMap<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>();
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que em:

`protected override void Configure()`

Está com erro, acredito que porque a versão do AutoMapper que estou usando é a mais recente, e a do tutorial é a 3.2.1, alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile.Configure: no suitable method found to override

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na versão 6.2.2 o mapeamento é feito via construtor, seus mapeamentos ficariam assim:
**DomainToViewModelMappingProfile:**

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
        CreateMap<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>();
    }
}
```

**ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile:**

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
        CreateMap<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>();
    }
}
```

**E a classe de configuração assim:**

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {

        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            x.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Barbetta,Consegui resolver o mesmo problema, só que na versão 7.1 do AutoMapper.