# Como utilizar DTO em ASP.NET CORE + DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou montando uma aplicação seguindo os padrões DDD. Gostaria de saber como usar o corretamente o padrão Data Transfer Object – DTO.

Com o pouco que eu li, cheguei à conclusão:
Estou utilizando ViewModel (uma representação da entidade para ser usada na View), então preciso converter essa ViewModel em DTO para transmitir para as outras camadas. Chegando ao domínio, eu preciso converter novamente de DTO para entidade e enviar a entidade para o repositório (persistência). O caminho inverso também é necessário no caso de consulta.

**A pergunta é:** Eu posso ter construtor na ViewModel que receba um DTO e crie uma ViewModel a partir do mesmo? E no DTO um construtor que crie um DTO a partir de uma ViewModel? O mesmo para a entidade.

Por exemplo:

```
public Class UsuarioViewModel{

    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string EMail {get; set;}
    public string Senha {get; set;}

    public UsuarioViewModel(){

    }

    public UsuarioViewModel(UsuarioDTO _usuariodto){
        Nome = _usuariodto.Nome,
        EMail = _usuariodto.EMail,
        Senha = _usuariodto.Senha
    }

}

public Clas UsuarioDTO{

    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string EMail {get; set;}
    public string Senha {get; set;}

    public UsuarioDTO(){
    }

    public UsuarioDTO(UsuarioViewModel _usuariovm){
        Nome = _usuariovm.Nome,
        EMail = _usuariovm.EMail,
        Senha = _usuariovm.Senha
    }

    public UsuarioDTO(Usuario _usuario){
        Nome = _usuario.Nome,
        EMail = _usuario.EMail,
        Senha = _usuario.Senha
    }
}

public Clas Usuario{

public string Nome {get; set;}
public string EMail {get; set;}
public string Senha {get; set;}

public Usuario(){
}

public UsuarioDTO(UsuarioDTO _usuarioDTO){
    Nome = _usuarioDTO.Nome,
    EMail = _usuarioDTO.EMail,
    Senha = _usuarioDTO.Senha
}

}

// Controller
_serviceApp.Add(new UsuarioDTO(usuarioVM));

//Service
_service.Add(new Usuario(usuarioDTO));

//Repositorio
_repositorio.add(Usuario usuario);
```

Posso trabalhar dessa forma?

Comment: De uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33005/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dto-e-viewmodel-em-projeto-asp-net-mvc), talvez ajude. Eu acho(Opnião), que na maioria dos casos, o MVVM já resolve 90% do casos. Como o Renan disse na resposta dele "não vejo necessiade de DTO a não ser que você faça muitas chamadas remotas para recuperar muitos dados"

Comment: @Diego Rafael Souza Obrigado pela Resposta!
Legal, utilizar DTO em situações mais complexas...
Agora, em relação ao MVVM seria algo do tipo:

 public void Adicionar(ClienteVM vm)
 {
            var cliente = new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = vm.ClienteId,
                Nome = vm.Nome,
                CPF = vm.CPF,
            };
            _clienteService.Adicionar(cliente);
 }

Simplesmente converto de ViewModel para Entidade e Vice e Versa?
Caso não seja dessa forma, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: @Barbetta Obrigado também!

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza se eu entendi bem, você está com duvida sobre passar os dados do `ViewModel` para o `Model`, correto, talvez essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285316/como-implementar-automapper-6-2-2/285319#285319) e essa [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230671/asp-net-c-ddd-problema-ao-passar-dados-da-entidade-para-viewmodel/230679#230679) te ajudem.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, boa tarde

A utilização de DTO com os modelos de visão (ViewModel) é possível, porém, em minha opinião é mais adequado em casos em que você utiliza uma ViewModel que se integra a partir de vários DTOs.

Pois, os ViewModels normalmente são dados compostos de um ou mais objetos, nesse caso o(s) DTO(s), mais as propriedades que queira adicionar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção mais razoável seria fazer um "mapeamento" de propriedades de um DTO com propriedades de um ViewModel, desvinculando qualquer dependência de um com o outro. Existem ferramentas que podem lhe ajudar com isso, como a biblioteca "Automapper", que você pode encontrar facilmente no Nuget. Ela faz uma leitura dos nomes das propridades de uma classe (através de reflection) e atribui os valores à uma instância de outra classe de propriedades com nomes semelhantes. Por exemplo:

```
//Cria uma intância de UsuarioDTO, com os valores contidos no objeto "usuarioViewModel"    
var dto = Mapper.Map<UsuarioDTO>(usuarioViewModel);
```